# Why does $f'(x_{(1)})=-r_{(1)}$ in conjugate gradient?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, gradient-descent

I am reading through the paper [Painless Conjugate Gradient by Jonathan Shewchuk](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15859n/RelatedWork/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) and have reached the following passage:

[image]

Everything in there makes sense up until he says $f'(x_{(1)})=-r_{(1)}$. How did he derive that? I'm having a lot of trouble visualizing why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be a little let down by my answer.

Shewchuk (1994, p. 6) wrote that the residual in the direction of the steepest descent was:
$$r_i = -f'{(x_i)}$$

If you multiply by -1 (flip the signs):

$$ (-1) * r_i = - f'{(x_i)} * (-1)$$
$$-r_i = f'{(x_i)}$$

or in other words

$$f'{(x_i)} = -r_i$$

Comment: Ok, I feel guilty. I did say that I understood everything up to that point - I should have said that relationship doesn't make sense to me. The error and the residual do, or at least I think they do, but not why the residual is equal to the directional derivative of the function of x.